# Adding this VNET would exceed the App Service Plan VNET limit of 1, but another AppServicePlan shows 2/1

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Via the portal, when trying to add a VNET Integration on an App Service that is linked to an App Service Plan that already has a VNET Integration (via another App Service), I get an error saying that "Adding this VNET would exceed the App Service Plan VNET limit of 1"

However, for another App Service Plan (created via Bicep), when looking at the VNET integration at the App Service Plan level, we were actually able to see 2/1
[image]

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Have you gone through this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807328/cant-configure-network-config-on-two-azure-web-apps/72809521#72809521 does this helpful ?

Comment: Not really because I understand there's a rule but I don't understand why I can circumvent the rule through Bicep deployment

Answer (score 0):

I think of below situation:

1. The ASP or web app might be very old where you had configured VNET integration and later might have deleted.

I dont think this is related to Bicep perhaps you could also be able to see this behavior even with portal or powershell.

I doubt if you could reciprocate this issue with new resource creation. If its only happening for this app service/plan then it could be because of the legacy metadata reside at Azure.

Comment: But it's a very recent AppService plan.. and I am able to reproduce the behavior. So far I have no explanation except a "bug" in the platform

Answer (score 0):

ASP Regional VNet integration amount is related to the ASP tier plan:

I checked on a Linux ASP (I assume that it works the same for Windows ASP):

- Dev/Test ASP - 1 subnet
- Production ASP - 2 subnets.

[image]